# Entry().get() doesn't work in Python 3.4

Tags: python, tkinter

Despite all attempts, I cannot seem to get Entry().get() to assign a string in an Entry window.  Here's a code snippet:

```
    Itx_bcn_ent = Entry(win).grid(row=1,column=1)
```

I define a button to call a function:

```
    btn = Button(win,text="Run",command=getnums).grid(row=5,column=3,padx=100)
```

Here's the function:
        def getnums():
                 Itx_bcn = Itx_bcn_ent.get()

When I run the script, I get the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1482, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python34\voltage_substate_GUI.py", line 7, in getnums
    Itx_bcn = Itx_bcn_ent.get()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I've seen the construct to use a Class StringVar() and the option "textvariable=" with the Entry() object, however doing this seems overly complicated as it just creates an additional set of variables between what's in the Entry window and the variable I am trying to assign.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 3):

`Entry.grid()` returns `None`, so when you do `something = Entry(root).grid()`, you're getting `something=None`.

This isn't a problem until you try to use that thing! That's why you're getting a `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'` error.

```
Itx_bcn_ent = Entry(win)
Itx_bcn_ent.grid(row=1,column=1)
```

Now your button works :), though you have the same problem with your `btn =` line. I've yet to have to reuse that assignment, so maybe just drop it?

```
Button(win,text="Run",command=getnums).grid(row=5,column=3,padx=100)
```